# How to stop gmail from periodically blocking smtp access from AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, smtp, gmail

I send e-mails via SMTP on AWS. Periodically google blocks access and I receive an e-mail like the one below:

```
Sign-in attempt was blocked
xxx@gmail.com
Someone just used your password to try to sign in to your account. Google blocked them, but you should check what happened.
```

I then change the e-mail password and update in AWS, and sending e-mail starts working again until google next blocks AWS access. I tried enabling access to less secure apps in my security settings, but that didn't work for me. Is there a permanent solution to enabling SMTP access from AWS ?

Comment: Why don't you send emails via SES?

Comment: Are you familiar with access for "less secure apps": https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en